# Does sale need to come before purchase to be considered a like-kind exchange

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, 1031-exchange, like-kind-exchange

**Does sale need to come before purchase in order to be considered a like-kind exchange and avoid capital gains tax?**

When selling your home (primary residence) and purchasing a new one does the sale of the existing home need to come before purchase of the new one? I found two pages on this but neither answers this question directly.

- https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/capitalgainhomesale.asp
- https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/like-kind-exchanges-real-estate-tax-tips

Comment: Updated the tags based on the question. I'm assuming you're talking about the US IRC Sec 1031 exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, the [IRC Sec. 1031](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1031) (like-kind exchange tax deferral) refers to investment properties, you cannot use it to defer tax recognition on the sale of your primary residence. For primary residences there's a different section, [IRC Sec. 121](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/121), that allows exclusion of up to $250K ($500K for MFJ taxpayers) from your income